# Unable to encode an unsaved parse file, working with ParseUser

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a signUp activity with a profile picture, but i get an error stating: Unable to encode an unsaved parse file. I have the same code in another Class and it doesn't have any problems.

I think that the problem could be using ParseUser instead of ParseObject. Please help me, here's my code.

```
    public class SignUpActivityStep3 extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final String YOUR_APPLICATION_ID = "kuN8ihs88AYhRR1jIWT9psCGUXxSOveJPqVVsBnq";
    public static final String YOUR_CLIENT_KEY = "vC4eA9CqulpgkxJ7sTPtoPSANkMxFeiFlYXwODYK";

    byte[] Image;
    ParseFile photo = null;
    String User, Pass, Email, Description;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signupstep3);

        Parse.initialize(this, YOUR_APPLICATION_ID, YOUR_CLIENT_KEY);

        EditText Desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
        Button Finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        User = intent.getStringExtra("User");
        Pass = intent.getStringExtra("Pass");
        Email = intent.getStringExtra("Email");
        Image = intent.getByteArrayExtra("Image");        

        photo = new ParseFile("userpicture.png", Image);
        photo.saveInBackground();

        savetoParse();


    }

    private void savetoParse() {

        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
        user.setUsername(User.toString());
        user.setPassword(Pass.toString());
        user.put("Profile", photo);
        user.setEmail(Email.toString());

        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {

                if (e != null) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Saving user failed." + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (e.getCode() == 202) {

                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Username already taken. \n Please choose another username.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Saved",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    /*Do some things here if you want to.*/

                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to wait for the Parse file to finish saving before attempting to sign up the user. You need to do something like this:

```
photo = new ParseFile("userpicture.png", Image);

file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    public void done(ParseException e) {
       // If successful add file to user and signUpInBackground
       if(null == e)
           savetoParse();
    }
});
```

Comment: Very much appreciated, short but most effective.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue but then I figured that for the image to be saved we need to login first, so either login with a user and password using `ParseUser.LogInBackGround` method or use `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` to enable automatic user creation and logging in.